# Python - how to terminate a threading.Timer class correctly?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, terminate

I'm currently experimentating around with threading.Timer, and somehow I'm not doing very well..
My goal is to run hundreds of functions, repeating all the time.
The problem is, that the usage of my RAM is growing and growing and growing, until the process stops.

This is how my code looks like:

```
from threading import Timer

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.timer = Timer(1, self.print_number)
        self.timer.start()

    def print_number(self):
        print "Number: %s"%self.number
        self.repeat()

    def repeat(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        #self.timer.join()
        #time.sleep(1)
        self.timer = Timer(3, self.print_number)
        self.timer.start()

for x in range(1, 300):
    Foo(x)
```

So, I've read that I can terminate a thread using .join() method after .cancel().
But when I do this I'm getting a `RuntimeError: (cannot join current thread)`.
On a similar topic I've read that I can use time.sleep after .cancel() to terminate a thread,
but that does nothing to the thread for me.

My questions: How can I properly terminate the threads in this code example and how can I stop the script from using more and more RAM, or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Sorry if I'm re-asking a question that has been asked already many times, but I'm searching and trying for hours and couldn't find a solution yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Just have a break condition in the loop.  The join at the end just makes sure all threads finish before moving forward.  I use this often with a Queue (you can find samples, Queue Work Task pattern or some similar search).

Alternatively, I use apscheduler when I just need things to run on a timer or some cron-like functionality.

```
import threading
import time

WORKERS = 300

class Worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            if self.number > 300:
                break

            print "Number: %s"%self.number
            self.number += 1
            time.sleep(3)

workers = []
for i in range(WORKERS):
    w = Worker(100)
    workers.append(w)
    w.start()

for w in workers: 
    w.join()
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of how you would do what I'm trying to achieve? I don't know much about threading, still learning.

Comment: Are you trying to run a function every 3 seconds up to 300 times?

Comment: Ahh I reread what you are trying to do.  Have you seen apscheduler?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but your example is not what I'm looking for. I have tried APscheduler, but it uses threading, so in the end, it results in the same. I need the script to be running infinitely, so each class needs to be executed as long as I kill the process. And I can't use time.sleep as it would cause the whole script to be paused, that's not what I want. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok... but it can't be that far off.  You want to run threads that keeps doing something, but you said you want it to terminate.  Based on what condition though?  When is a thread considered to be "done"?  time.sleep() only pauses within that thread, not the whole script.

Comment: I guess I was not specific enough. The for-loop should just indicate that I'm trying to infinitely repeat a function inside of a class (each function having different values for their variables). The problem is, sooner or later, the free memory is getting less and less and every class stops working, raising "error can't start new thread". So I thought the threads are not being terminated correctly and it's taking more and more free memory. So my actual question is, why is the script taking exponentially more RAM and cannot start new threads anymore, even though threads are being terminated?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are creating a long call stack which is chewing up your RAM.  If you are trying to open up 300 threads that do something, and it waits for all 300 parallel threads to complete before ending the program, then that's what the code I posted does.